# Can't open connection to SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

When I try to connect to the MS SQL server in the local domain with SQL with SQL server authentication using the following code fails:

```
SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(conString);
sql.Open();
sql.Close();
```

I can connect to my local SQLExpress test database just fine, using either windows or sql authentication. I tried using many different connections strings for the domain database, including using the connection string generated by (successfully) adding the server as a `DataSource`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: When I add the server in the server explorer of visual studio, I can connect successfully. I would assume that the connection string thereby generated is valid:

```
Data Source=mySubDomain.myDomain.local;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;
```

I checked and remote connections are allowed. I do not have permission to access the windows server which the sql server is running on, so I can't check any further settings.

EDIT 2: The following message comes with the exception:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

EDIT 3:
I tested my application on a different computer in the same domain, and it worked. Does someone have a clue what's going on or how I could find out?

Comment: in the code shown, the only thing "wrong" is the lack of a `using` ;p But: without visibility of the connection-string (fudging any passwords etc), how can we comment? Also: do you have visibility-of and access-to the server/database? Meaning: does it work in other tools, such as SSMS?

Comment: Of course we need more details from inner exception and it should tell you the exact reason. However, do make sure that the connection string is per the SQL instance that you are trying to connnect with . Refer: http://www.connectionstrings.com/  . Another thing that you would like to see is the remote connection is enabled. For that you need to go through with the sQL steps similar to mention here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Do provide more details, otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Without knowing your connection string and exact error, it will be a bit hard to guess, but presumably you've forgot to set Trusted_Connection=True; inside your connection string. Please post the exception you're getting and the connection string you are using, and we'll find a solution.

Comment: @ChengLi does it fail from your machine, the machine where it works in the VS IDE? a very very common issue is firewall configuration, so if it is failing from another machine, that would be my first thought

Comment: @MarcGravell I will test it on other machines in a bit, but yes, it works in visual studio and server manager but not with my app, on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

The `Group Policy` or `firewall` (or both, not sure) of this company domain make my .exe file (and any other .exe) behave in the following way:

- Launching it from `C:\Program Files` (or `C:\Program Files (x86)`) as any user works fine
- Launching it from anywhere else as a normal user is not allowed and fails
- Launching it from anywhere else as a local admin will execute the application, but **connections are blocked**